# Is it possible set Private Browsing or Incognito as default, and log in to access history/stored logins?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari

I love private browsing and I always set up a private or incognito browser when I am letting others use my computer for a few minutes.

I think it would be fantastic if private browsing was enabled by default and a simple login was required to access stored login sessions, saved passwords, and history.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To setup private browsing by default, simply adjust your shortcut for the browser:

```
firefox.exe -private
chrome.exe --incognito
iexplorer.exe -private
```

For Safari it gets tricky, because you have to edit the plist file (and as far as I know, no way to do this on the fly and then have it reset).

The other common way to do this is to setup a default guest profile and adjust the shortcuts accordingly.

Some browsers provide profiles - and you can adjust the shortcut to load the profile that you want. For firefox, launch with `-profilemanager` to manage your profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're browsing on a computer, you can try **DuckDuckGo**. It is the default privacy mode, using the private search engine.

However, if you want to use mobile to browse, I recommend using **[Private Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privatebrowser.securebrowsing.incognito&referrer=utm_source%3Dforum)**, which also has the default incognito mode and private search engine, but is lighter and simpler,no more than 5M.
**Most importantly, it locks the bookmark and makes me feel secure.**

Hope it helps.